# Jasper Studio: Aggregating JDBC Domain data

Tags: jasper-reports, aggregation

My question is related to the question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802395/jasper-studio-reference-domain-dataset-in-subdataset-sql-query), but i've changed my approach.

I need to create a basic variance report, that shows volumes for two dates and the difference between these volumes.

I have an SQL query that uses a subquery to give me the appropriate aggregation for my data.

My problem is that I have to use a JDBC domain datasource and cannot get the results appropriately aggregated in Studio.

**My domain dataset looks like this:**

> ```
> ID Date        Volume
> 1  2015-10-05  100
> 1  2015-10-06  200
> 2  2015-10-05  800
> 2  2015-10-06  700
> ```

**Desired Results Table Sorted by VolDiff**

> ```
> ID VolDate1  VolDate2  VolDiff  
> 2  800       700      -100      
> 1  100       200       100
> ```

**I've tried several ways to do this in Studio:**

- Crosstab

  - Problem: it's impossible to sort by variable or calculated measure:
  - https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1053666/sorting-crosstab-measures-variable-total
- Non structured - textfields in a group band

  - Problem: cannot conditionally format rows in a Group Footer band
- Multiple tables

  - Problem: couldn't figure out how to feed return values from table results to a third volume-difference table
- Table in Summary band

  - Problem: can't get both date vols on one row
  - With this solution my table ends up looking like:

> ```
>     ID VolDate1  VolDate2  VolDiff
>     2  800         0      -800
>     2    0       700       700
>     1  100         0      -100
>     1    0       200       200
> ```

```
instead of:
```

> ```
>     ID VolDate1  VolDate2  VolDiff
>     2  800       700      -100
>     1  100       200       100
> ```

Comment: It can be easy done with crosstab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My steps to get the crosstab working with calculated variables:

**Configuring the [crosstab](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539418/crosstabs-andor-crosstab-documentation):**

- Put my dates as the column (ID as rows and Volume as
  measure)
- Within the crosstab, change the calculation function for my measure to "Sum"

**Calculate Volume Difference and add to crosstab:**

- Create 2 variables within Main Dataset that give volume for each day:

  ```
  Vol_Date1: IF($F{dateSet.RecordDate}.equals($P{RecordDate_0_1}), $F{productionSet.OilProduction},0.0)
  ```
- Create 3rd variable within Main Dataset that calculates the difference:

  ```
  Vol_Diff: $V{Vol_Date2}-$V{Vol_Date1}
  ```
- Variable Properties: To get the difference variable to correctly:

  ```
  Vol_Date1:              Calculation = First, Increment Type = None, Reset Type = [Group] ID
  Vol_Date2 and Vol_Diff: Calculation = None, Increment Type = None, Reset Type = Report
  ```
- Create Measure within crosstab where value expression is $V{Vol_Diff}; Calcuation = No Calculation Function